# Different output for two code snippets when the same is expected

Tags: group-by

I don't understand why I am getting **nan** values in the output for the second code snippet, although the Dataframe is the same. I expect it to be the same as my first output.

First snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                   'Value': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]})
print(df)

  Category  Value
0        A      1
1        A      2
2        B      3
3        B      3
4        C      4

value_counts = df.groupby('Category').value_counts().reset_index(name='value_counts')
print(value_counts)

  Category  Value  value_counts
0        A      1             1
1        A      2             1
2        B      3             2
3        C      4             1
```

Second snippet:

```py
def get_value_counts_dict(group):
    return group.value_counts().to_dict()

df['value_counts'] = df.groupby('Category')['Value'].transform(get_value_counts_dict)

print(df)

  Category  Value  value_counts
0        A      1           NaN
1        A      2           1.0
2        B      3           NaN
3        B      3           2.0
4        C      4           1.0
```